# Integral using trig substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, derivatives

The problem says to find the arc length of the curve which isn't that bad. I know the formula for the arc length of $r(t)$ is: $\int_a^b |r'(t)|\,dt$.

The equation is this:  $x=\cos(3t), y=\sin(3t), z=t^2$; from $t = 0$ to $t = \pi/2$

Since I am given the equation in parametric form, I can rewrite it as $r(t)=\langle \cos(3t), \sin(3t), t^2\rangle$

So $r'(t) = \langle -3\sin(3t), 3\cos(3t), 2t\rangle$

Next I need to solve for the magnitude

$$|r'(t)|= \sqrt{(-3\sin(3t))^2+(3\cos(3t))^2+(2t)^2}=\sqrt{9\sin^2(3t)+9\cos^2(3t)+4t^2}=\sqrt{9(\sin^2(3t)+\cos^2(3t))+4t^2}=\sqrt{9(1)+4t^2}=\sqrt{9+4t^2}$$

Now that I have the magnitude of the derivative, it's time to plug that into the integral. This is where I get lost.

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{9+4t^2} \, dt$

I am not sure what to do from here. I know I can't do a u-substitution or integration by parts. I think this is a trig substitution? Tangent if I recall? I'm just not sure what to do when I get past here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straightforward to see that $1+\tan^2(x)= \sec^2(x)$. So making the substitution $t= \frac{3}{2}\tan(u)$ should do the trick. As for the limits, when $t=0$, $u=0$. And if $t=\pi/2$, the bound will be $u=\tan^{-1}(\frac{\pi}{3})$. It'll simplify later.

Comment: Ah 3/2, okay. For some reason I was wanting to do 9/4 but I forgot that those would be squared. No wonder I was getting the wrong answer. A silly mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: I am confused on the changing of my limits. Originally they're from 0 to $\pi/2$ So when I set $t=3/2 tan(u)$ what would they be?

Comment: Use pi/2 = 3/2 tan(u) and solve for u. Same for zero...